# what does it mean to have slightly higher valid error rate, very high and similar valid error rate compared to train and test?

Tags: cross-validation, error, validation

the dataset is split into 3 categories: train, test, valid. after training the error rates we see have these values.

case 1

- 1% error on the training set.
- 5% error on training dev set.
- 5% error on the dev set.

the model is underfit as it should show less or same error rate btw valid ~ test dataset

case 2

- 11% error on the training set.
- 12% error on training dev set.
- 13% error on the dev set

the model is fine

case 3

- 10.5% error on the training set.
- 11.5% error on training dev set.
- 21% error on the dev set.

huge 21% valid error rate - the model has huge underfit

am i correct?